# Connect Sony SmartEyeGlass to Wifi

Tags: wifi, sony-smarteyeglass

today a SmartEyrGlass arrived at the office and I am having trouble connecting it to the wifi to take pictures.

The manual just says:

> Turn on wireless LAN on your smartphone.

And in the settings off the glass it only displays the MAC address of the device.

I looked online for a full manual, but I couldn't find any.

What do I need to do to take pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will automatically connect over wireless LAN when you start the Camera application.

For connection, initial pairing over bluetooth is enough. Device will switch to WLAN automatically when application needs it.

Start Camera and you will see it is starting to connect.