# installing wifi option in sony smart glass

Tags: wifi, sony-smarteyeglass

I have been using sony smart glass in my project.It is very important for me to access wifi. how can i connect..? it just gives w-lan address when i click w-lan option in glass.I went through sony website but i couldnt find anything related to it. I also found this question in stackflow asked by some other user.The solution given to him was.,the glass can connect automatically itself. If w-lan is password protected how can it connect automatically.? because it is not working.is there any other option available.? like is it possible to install wifi option.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially for SmartEyeglass to work with your device you have to connect over Bluetooth, but if you need extra performance from the glasses you can shift it in to high-power mode. If you activate the camera button on the glasses they will automatically switch to high-power mode. If you are referring to this question then that is what it is talking about:

[Connect Sony SmartEyeGlass to Wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048008/connect-sony-smarteyeglass-to-wifi)

Here is more information about high power mode
https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/guides/settings/#toc-2

Unfortunately there is no way for you to use the wifi connection other than this. Hope that helps